# DataTable throws exception in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, dataset, task-parallel-library

When I use `DataTable` with `Parallel.ForEach`, I am getting :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

Please help me to solve it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = CreateTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("C");
    //Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, dt.Rows.Count), range =>
    //{
    //    for (int j = range.Item1; j < range.Item2; j++)
    //    {
    //         dt.Rows[j]["C"] = dt.Rows[j]["A"] + "-" + dt.Rows[j]["B"];
    //    }
    //});

    Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), row =>
    {
        row["C"] = row["A"] + "-" + row["B"];                
    });
}

private static DataTable CreateTable()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("A");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("B");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add("A" + i, "B" + i);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not thread-safe; you cannot run multiple updates on it in parallel.

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.